# Stack Overflow does not display properly, many errors

Tags: support, error-message, google-chrome

In recent days, all of the Stack Overflow website does not show up as it is supposed to be on my computer.

For example, when I open [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298797/inserting-a-row-at-a-specific-location-in-a-2d-array-in-numpy) link, it is shown like this:
[image]

The errors (in Google Chrome, right click and choose 'Inspect'):
[image]

I've no idea what these errors mean. What should I do?

By the way, I am using [OS X v10.11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_El_Capitan) (El Capitan) with Google Chrome version 51.0.2704.106 (64-bit).

Comment: Try using just regular HTTP (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298797/inserting-a-row-at-a-specific-location-in-a-2d-array-in-numpy). Does that work? If so, I suspect some ISP/network issue with SSL (TLS).

Comment: See [What else do I need](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/158100). One red flag is the blocking of gravatar.com. I suspect your ISP or some party upstream might block more from that list.

Comment: It works! Previously, I've tried to change 'https' to 'http' but it did not work. Now I realise it was changed back to 'https' by an Chrome extension named "HTTPS Everywhere" which I installed (some websites are blocked when 'http' is used). When I disable it, the stackoverflow website shows properly. Thank you very much.  @hichris123

Comment: That "ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE" kind of indicates a TSL issue.

Comment: I have googled a little bit about TLS problem, and it seems too complicated to deal with for me...   @Braiam